# Rails: Formatting a date: "HH:MM" for today, "Yesterday" for yesterday, "Weekday" for other days of last week, "DD.MM." for everything else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I'm sure there is a already a solution for what I need, but I guess I don't know what to search for. Any pointings into the right direction?

I'm thinking of something like Rails' `distance_of_time_in_words_to_now`.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the date a Ruby Date object?

Answer (score 10):

I believe you could use a helper like this.

```
def custom_format(date)
  if date == Date.today
    "Today"
  elsif date == Date.yesterday
    "Yesterday"
  elsif (date > Date.today - 7) && (date < Date.yesterday)
    date.strftime("%A")
  else
    date.strftime("%B %-d")
  end
end
```

Didn't test the code, it's just a pointer to your problem.

Comment: I guess you mean `==`, not `=`.

Comment: Instead of "Weekday" you want `date.strftime("%A")`

Comment: @steenslag Oh yeah, typo there.

Answer (score 5):

Create a file .../config/initializers/time_format.rb and put this code in it:

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:humanized_ago]  = ->(time) do
  st = Time.now.beginning_of_day
  nd = Time.now.end_of_day

  case 
  when time.between?(st + 1.day, nd + 1.day)
    "Tomorrow #{time.strftime('%H:%M')}"
  when time.between?(st, nd)
    "Today #{time.strftime('%H:%M')}"
  when time.between?(st - 1.day, nd - 1.day)
    "Yesterday #{time.strftime('%H:%M')}"
  when time.between?(st - 6.day, nd - 2.day)
    time.strftime('%a %H:%M')
  else 
    time.strftime('%y-%b-%d %H:%M')
  end
end
```

On a Rails Time object, call function `time.to_s(:humanized_ago)`. If you don't like the symbol ":humanized_ago", change it it whatever you want in the first line of time_format.rb." If you want other formatting, you can figure it out.

I wrote the comparisons the way I did for a reason. I couldn't find a way to use the Ruby built-in ranges to test Time, and you need to be able to test Time intervals excluding the end point.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<%= time_ago_in_words(time) %> ago
```